# How to extend component in Typescript, and figuring out required arguments? Use case: Angular - extending mat-side-nav

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, oop, angular-material2

**Background:**

The dynamics of the Angular Material Design [mat-side-nav component](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview) is such, that it requires the following structure:

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

`<mat-sidenav>` and `<mat-sidenav-content>` must be direct descendants of the `<mat-sidenav-container>` parent component. Therefore, if I would like to create a re-usable side nav across the app, with specific list items, I would have to do the following:

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav>
   <app-sidenav></app-sidenav><!--I've just been added-->
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**Attempted Solution:**

Therefore I am attempting to extend the `<mat-sidenav>` component within my app-sidenav component, so it can easily be re-used throughout app, like such:

```
export class SideNavComponent extends MatSidenav implements AfterContentInit { 
//..

constructor() {
  super();
}
```

So that I can simply do:

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <app-sidenav> <!--I'm now here instead of <mat-sidenav> -->
  </app-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**Issue:** 
The typescript compiler will complain `error TS2554: Expected 6 arguments, but got 0.` when attempting to extend MatSidenav.

**Question:**

1. Why would by extending the MatSideNav, would I now require 6 arguments?
2. Is there a way for me to find out what those 6 arguments are, in this situation, and other similar typescript situations as to what the arguments should be?

Thank you, and any suggestions are more than appreciated.

Comment: You can omit constructor in child class, thus you don't need to care about parameters (make sure this works in both JIT and AOT mode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need this 6 parameters. You can check them in the code source of Angular Material2. As for why, it's a basic heritage rule. When you call super, you basically call the parent's class constructor (which in this case requires 6 parameters)

```
              private _elementRef: ElementRef,
              private _focusTrapFactory: FocusTrapFactory,
              private _focusMonitor: FocusMonitor,
              private _platform: Platform,
              private _ngZone: NgZone,
              @Optional() @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _doc: Document
```